# Preventing infinite console loop

Tags: javascript, angular

We have an Angular app that will trigger an infinite loop when trying to `console.log`

Ex:

on `App.component.html` file I commented out the rest of the code and only showing:

```js
{{ testConsole() }}
```

and on `App.component.ts` file I added the method:

```js
testConsole() {
   console.log('test')
}
```

the output is:

[image]

What might cause this issue?

Comment: i think your  `App.component.html`  file rendering multiple time is there any parent component of your `App.component.html`

Comment: If you only have that code, what's logging the `Array []` in your screenshot then?

Comment: You need to look at your app component and all its dependencies and figure out what is causing it to trigger an update. Your template code is only invoked if it thinks it needs to rerender itself, and apparently some parent component or code is making changes.

Comment: @Jay Hello, We have exported modules, we have core modules and shared module, and other module. Im trying to comment out some of the exported module and couldn't point out which is cause the problem.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I added that. my bad should've removed it.

Comment: @JeffMercado Is there a way to figure that out using `Angury` its an Angular app dev tools. Right now I'm just commenting out modules and it's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest never to call/invoke a function from the html to render.
Do whatever you need to do before rendering itself.. such that you will always render only the variables and not functions in your render html template.

when you add the function to html render, it will be called multiple times when you mouse move, scroll, and do any such things.

Comment: I don't think it's the wrong way to call a method inside the HTML file. Some Angular samples do that, and I've seen projects that do the same thing. This is just me showing the problem. We just found out when we were trying to debug something at work. Also this should be just a comment and not an answer. Thank you tho. I appreciate it.